# Android Studio Layout Editor doesn't show Layout

Tags: android, android-studio, layout, graphical-layout-editor

I'm trying to create a simple app interface using a navigation fragment, which swaps fragments in and out with a bottom navigation bar controlled by a `navController`.

When I run the app it works as expected, however in the **activity_main.xml** file it doesn't show me the layout I see when I run the application. Is there any reason for this?

The code for the activity layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
        <!--android:background="#fff"/>-->

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_graph" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe include what it looks like?

Comment: Of course it won't be the same, on the editor you won't see the fragment loaded as you see it when you run the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FragmentContainerView` is a place holder that can show a fragment at a time when you do fragment transaction; so at design time, Android studio not sure which fragment that will be hosted first in this place holder, so it keeps it blank.

But if you want to show the start_destination fragment in the `navigation_graph` you can use the `tools:layout` attribute, and this only works in design time, not the run time.

Assuming the name of the fragment layout that you want to host first in the `FragmentContainerView` is `fragment_start_destination`

```
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_start_destination"
```

Comment: Dam @Zain how is it that you always beat me to the punch.